# How can I override the merge-base in a git merge?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

My repository has cherry-picks recorded as merges. It throws of git's selection of merge-base. Is it possible to specify the merge-base? If so, how?

*Example*: f is branched from master at A. C is cherry-picked to f, but misleadingly committed as a merge with K and C as parents.

```
A-B-C   master
\   \  
 K---C'-L   f
```

When merging f into master git will find C as best common ancestor and use it as Base. Since B is included at Base, but is missing at f it will be undone by the merge. Using A as base would give a correct merge.

Edit: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32350141/470022) rules out plan B asked about below. So, hopefully someone can answer: **How can I specify the merge-base in a git merge?**

---

Edit, plan B: The repository has become like that by using tfs-git to fetch from two tfs-branches that have a cherry-pick-workflow. "Merge selected range" of one changeset shows up as a full merge in git. An alternative solution would be to somehow configure git-tfs to not create merge-commits. (To stop cherry-picking for all is not at an option.)

Comment: Hi @Grastveit, i'm not sure if i understand your problem, if you cherry-pick `C` but not `B` isn't it intended, that `B` is concluded from the further work? If not shouldn't `B` also be picked or in your example just proceeded on `C`?

Comment: @florianb: Some other at the team has done "Merge selected range" and merged only C over to branch f and checked in. The I have fetched with git-tfs and their checkin appears as a merge in my git-repository. In git a merge means merge all changes, so in C' is assumed to to include changes both from B and C. Clearer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I specify the merge-base in a git merge?

With grafts:

```
echo $(git rev-parse tip1 mybase) >>.git/info/grafts
echo $(git rev-parse tip2 mybase) >>.git/info/grafts

git checkout tip1
git merge tip2

rm .git/info/grafts
```

**edit** from comment: with annotated tags, specify `^{}` at the end of your references, `tip1^{}` etc, to have rev-parse chase down and print the commit's id rather than being happy with the tag's.

Comment: FWIW `echo $(foo) >> file` is the same as just `foo >> file`.

Comment: @amalloy I think you might have forgotten about shell wordsplitting. . . the echo converts two lines of rev-parse output into a single line of echo output.

Comment: @amalloy typo fixed, thanks. [It really is about wordsplitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html), the shell passes each word to echo as a separate argument, with word boundaries identified as specified by the `IFS` variable, ordinarily it's space/tab/newline runs.  Try `(IFS=: ; printf '%s\n' $PATH )`.

Comment: Muahaha, the power! I was using the vanilla cmd, but switched to git bash now. Also I did a small mistake of specifying base by tag. The merge failed because apparently rev-parse returned the SHA of the tag-object, not the commit-SHA.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to jthill's answer.

I had a similar problem and as *<GIT_DIR>/info/grafts* is now deprecated, here how I solved the same problem with `git replace`:

```
git replace --graft tip1 mybase
git replace --graft tip2 mybase

git checkout tip1
git merge tip2

git replace -d tip2
git replace -d tip1~1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that "cherry-picking" (in a Git manner) seems to be **no** function or [planned workflow](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2638075-tfs-to-merge-multiple-non-continuous-changesets) of the Team Foundation Server Versioncontrol.

---

The "cherry-pick" command of git applies "the change introduced by the [given] commit[s] at the tip of the [...] branch and create[s] a new commit with [those] change[s]." (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

The TFSVSC has no "cherry-picking" command but the possibility to do "Merge [a] selected range" or a "partial merge" which merges the specified (subsequential) changesets into a new changeset on a different branch (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dstfs/archive/2009/05/04/partial-merges-in-tfs-a-guide.aspx).

And this is where `git-tfs` seems to come to its limits (at the moment of writing) - [Invalid selective merges instead of cherry picks](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/822). There (currently) seems to be no failsafe way to translate partial merges into corresponding git-cherry-picks where git-merge delivers wrong results due to the difference that Git bases on snapshots (and therefore needs a dependency tree) compared to TFS which bases on changesets.

---

I currently think you have to wait until that issue of git-tfs gets fixed, or do the cherry-picking in the git-repository. Another approach could be to checkout the tfs-repository and commit it to the git-repo, but that will dismiss your commit-history during the transfer.

Comment: Thanks for good answer that definitely rules out "plan B" as a solution. That leaves specifying merge-base as way to make it work. I'll wait a bit and see...